# use Django database models externally

Tags: python, django, sqlite

My site is named ficosa. I have a Django server set up with a sqlite database that contains a table named core_Data. Now, I am developing a python file named `serverMQTT.py` that should insert data into that sqlite database. This file is outside Django so in order to import the Django models from ficosa site I call django.setup()

```
import django
from django.conf import settings
from ficosa import settings as fsettings

settings.configure(default_settings=fsettings, DEBUG=True)

django.setup()
```

## Now this script or any imported module can use any part of Django it needs.

```
from core.models import Data
```

However, I am having an error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LOGGING_CONFIG'

I would be gratefull if sombody could help me

Comment: As a side note, do not use SQLite in production unless you have good reason to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how you configure settings in a standalone app. Note what the documentation says:

> Be aware that if you do pass in a new default module, it entirely replaces the Django defaults, so you must specify a value for every possible setting that might be used in that code you are importing.

Presumably, your `fsettings` module only contains database settings. In which case, just override that one thing:

```
settings.configure(DATABASES=fsettings.DATABASES, DEBUG=True)
```